# How to understand frames in DevTools Timeline?

Tags: javascript, performance, profiling, google-chrome-devtools, frame-rate

This question is somewhat a child of this one - [How to understand devtools timeline properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37438499/how-to-understand-devtools-timeline-properly)

Now I have a different question about frames rendering. Not "what's happening", but "why it's happening".

Here is the picture:

[image]

As you can see here, I have a lot of idle time between two browser "activities". The first one(on the left) is sending the request. The second(on the right) receives the response. The question about time between those two "activities". How browser splits the frames? Why the first frame after request is so long?

[image]

It seems like nothing happens here. Probably, taking from my previous question, I can make  it makes some internal browser work, but, why it's so long? Why browser doesn't split the internal activities(if any) in the next frames? There are a lot of small and fast frames left.

I would highly appreciate any references and notes on that topic, because right now we are in the middle of performance analysis of our app.